# what's the meaning of Free Memory for Android APP?

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

I have a problem. My App's memory is taken away by system when in background. So, I try to release some resource, like bitmap, to avoid this. But from the memory tool in Android Studio, I found that there are two kinds of data about memory. One is "Free" and the other is "Allocated". After recycling bitmap, the Allocated part get down while the Free part get higher. On other hand, I check the cellphone's setting->application management->running, it shows that my APP hold nearly the same memory as the one before I recycled bitmap and the memory usage just equal to the Free part+Allocated part.
I'm confused. Is the freed memory by recycling bitmap still occupied by my APP in view of system? If so, my app is still facing the risk of being killed. How can I save my APP in background?